# AWS API Gateway / Cognito Userpools / Lambdas not able to pass caller credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I'm working on an AWS API Gateway implementation with a Lambda backend. I use the API Gateway integration with the Cognito Userpools (fairly new) instead of building a custom authorizer using Lambda (which was the recommended way before it was integrated).

I've created a proof of concept (javascript) that authenticates a user with Cognito and then makes a call to the API Gateway with those credentials. So, basically, the end call to the API Gateway is with the JWT token that I received from Cognito (result.idToken.jwtToken) in the Authorization header. This all works and I can validate that only with this token you can access the API.

All working fine, but now I want to get access to the Cognito identity in my Lambda; for instance the identy id or the name or email. I have read how to map all the parameters, but I'm actually just using the standard 'Method Request Passthrough' template in the integration request. I log all the parameters in the lambda and all the 'cognito' parameters are empty.

I've looked through many similar questions and they all propose to enable the 'Invoke with caller credentials' checkbox on the integration request. That makes perfect sense.

**However**, this checkbox can only be enabled if you are using **AWS_IAM** as authorization and **not** if you have selected your cognito UserPool. So it is just not possible to select it and is actually disabled.

Does anybody know what to do in this case? Is this still work in progress, or is there a reason why you can't enable this and get the cognito credentials in your Lambda?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you share your use case that you need the caller credentials from Cognito UserPool since you can access the principal user identification in your Lambda function?

Comment: Sure; we need to log/store some information about which user accessed what data (plus some more information) for reporting. For this we need some more user information. I would expect this to be sent, because in the 'Method Request Passthrough' template, some of the cognito fields are explicitly mapped ('cognito-authentication-provider', 'cognito-authentication-type', 'cognito-identity-id', 'cognito-identity-pool-id'. But they are all empty once the lambda is reached. Also, I checked the 'authorizer-principal-id' which is also empty. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can access the "sub" or "email" by "$context.authorizer.claims.sub",
"$context.authorizer.claims.email"

Comment: Many thanks! That did the trick. I also found two other articles with the same solution after looking for the properties you mentioned. There is also a suggestion that the standard API Gateway 'Method Request Passthrough' template to be adjusted so these properties are passed as standard (which is a great idea and would save a lot of time). Articles here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=739295 and https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/92. Thanks again. If you want you can submit it as an answer so I can accept that.

Comment: I struggled to solve this with node lambda functions, apiGateway, cognito, all deployed using a sam template.yml. I documented my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72694204/2827300

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to log the user information in your backend, you can use `$context.authorizer.claims.sub` and `$context.authorizer.claims.email` to get the **sub** and **email** for your Cognito user pool.

Here is the documentation about [**Use Amazon Cognito Your User Pool**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html) in API Gateway

Comment: I tried this but I am getting empty values on the backend:

{
  "context": {
    "sub": "",
    "email": ""
  }
}

Comment: @Ka Hou Ieong, is it still up to date answer? In last days, I found a few answers like your with comments added during last days that these `claims` and `$context` are blank.

Comment: Umm I can't figure out what the equivalent is for a Java lambda? (there is no `getAuthorizer` on the `context` object

Comment: In Java this'd be APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent (from the input) `.getRequestContext()` (ProxyRequestContext) `.getAuthorizer()` (Map<String, Object>) `.get("claims")` (Map<String, String> I think) `.get("sub")`. Note that you won't get an Authorizer if you're testing it through the API Gateway.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else still struggling to obtain the IdentityId in a Lambda Function invoked via API-Gateway with a Cognito User Pool Authorizer, I finally was able to use the jwtToken passed into the `Authorization` header to get the IdentityId by using the following code in my JavaScript Lambda Function:

```
const IDENTITY_POOL_ID = "us-west-2:7y812k8a-1w26-8dk4-84iw-2kdi849sku72"
const USER_POOL_ID = "cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_an976DxVk"
const { CognitoIdentityClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity");
const { fromCognitoIdentityPool } = require("@aws-sdk/credential-provider-cognito-identity");

exports.handler = async (event,context) => {
        const cognitoidentity = new CognitoIdentityClient({
            credentials:  fromCognitoIdentityPool({
                client: new CognitoIdentityClient(),
                identityPoolId: IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
                logins: {
                    [USER_POOL_ID]:event.headers.Authorization
                }
            }),
        });

        var credentials = await cognitoidentity.config.credentials()
        var identity_ID =  credentials.identityId
        console.log( identity_ID)

        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT"
             }, 
            body:JSON.stringify(identity_ID)
        };
        return response;
}
```

After a Cognito User has signed in to my application, I can use the Auth directive of `aws-amplify` and `fetch()` in my React-Native app to invoke the lambda function shown above by sending a request to my API-Gateway trigger (authenticated with a Cognito User Pool Authorizer) by calling the following code:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
var APIGatewayEndpointURL = 'https://5lstgsolr2.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/default/-'
var response = {}

async function getIdentityId () {   
       var session = await Auth.currentSession()
       var IdToken = await session.getIdToken()
       var jwtToken = await IdToken.getJwtToken()

       var payload = {}
       
       await fetch(APIGatewayEndpointURL, {method:"POST", body:JSON.stringify(payload), headers:{Authorization:jwtToken}})
         .then(async(result) => {
             response = await result.json()
             console.log(response)
          })
}
```

More info on how to Authenticate using `aws-amplify` can be found here https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/react-native/#using-withauthenticator-hoc