# How to pass cognito authentication token in the headers through api gateway to a lambda function

Tags: authorization, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am working on a full-stack project. And I use AWS cognito to do the Authentication part.
And on my front-end, I can get the idToken successfully and put into the method headers.
Here is the get method code:

```
          Axios.get(`url`, {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': Token
                }
            })
```

On the backend, I use AWS api gateway and lambda. As I understand, if I want to get the token in the lamdba, I have to set up the mapping template in the Integration Request of APIgateway.
So here is what I write, but I can't get the idToken.
Anyone knows the correct way to get the idToken?

```
{
  
  "idToken":"$context.authorizer.claims.authorization"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I close this question by myself.
After my search, if you  use AWS Auth cognit and you want to get the properties in the token, please refer to this doc:

idToken palyload
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html
api gateway mapping template:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference.

ex: if you want to get the userName from the id token, on the mapping template, it should be:

```
{
    "userName" : "$context.authorizer.claims['cognito:username']"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still struggled with this when using a node lambda function to grab the user details of the user accessing the apiGateway which was all configured using the sam template.yml

Here is my solution:

Set up my template.yml

```
GetMethod:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/getMethod.js
      Handler: getMethod.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Timeout: 60
      Policies:
         - DynamoDBReadPolicy:
            TableName: !Ref SomeTable
      Events:
        ApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /some/path
            Method: get
            Auth:
              Authorizer: SomeApiCognitoAuthorizer
            RestApiId:
              Ref: SomeApiGateway
SomeApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: {Get this from cognito}
      Cors: #"'*'"
        AllowHeaders: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'"
        AllowMethods: "'GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS'"
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          SomeApiCognitoAuthorizer:
            UserPoolArn: 
              - {Get this from the cognito settings}
            Identity: 
              Header: "Authorization"
```

Then set up the Lambda Function `src/getMethod.js`

```
exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
  console.log(event.requestContext.authorizer.claims);
}
```

Run deploy

```
sam package --template-file template.yml --output-template-file package.yml --s3-bucket {BLAH} --region eu-west-1 --profile {aws profile}
```

```
sam deploy --template-file package.yml --stack-name {BLAH} --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --region eu-west-1 --profile {aws profile}
```

Then go check cloudwatch on the Function